# Django vs Django-CMS -business compare site

Tags: django, django-cms

I've developing in django for the past few months and I find it extremely great.
My next project is a price-comparing site for local businesses - where each user can add business and comment on each.
The admin of the site won't be a programmer, but with basic knowledge in web and python.
Should I stick to the old familiar django or should I try it out?
Thanks :)
Matan.

Answer (score 0):

django CMS is built on top of Django and meant to be integrated into existing Django applications or extended with new ones. So your question is flawed.

So instead ask yourself if you need CMS functionality (pages managed by your admins). It sounds like your main app (the compare bit) is better handled by a Django application, but maybe you want the site admin to be able to easily edit the About Us page etc, this is where django CMS could come in handy.

Comment: So you're saying I should make the app in clean django and then connect the cms? because django-cms has tutorials about setting up websites from scratch too..

Comment: pretty much. django CMS is just another Django app you can add to your project.